# Doubt of inclusion-exclusion principle in a bitwise arithmetic problem

Tags: combinatorics

The problem:

> Jzzhu have $n$ non-negative integers $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$. We will call a sequence of indexes $i_1, i_2, ..., i_k$ $(1 ≤ i_1 < i_2 < ... < i_k ≤ n)$ a group of size $k$.
>
> Jzzhu wonders, how many groups exists such that $a_{i1} \& a_{i2} \& ... \& a_{ik} = 0$ $(1 ≤ k ≤ n)$? Help him and print this number modulo 1000000007 (109 + 7).
>
> Operation $x \& y$ denotes bitwise `AND` operation of two numbers.

[The original problem on Codeforces](http://codeforces.com/contest/449/problem/D)

[The official tutorial of this problem](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/13112)

I have to admitted that the "tutorial" of this problem is very succinct and abstract. So I actually didn't understand the whole illustration, but let's focus on some points:

1. How is inclusion-exclusion principle applied in this problem?
2. Why the range of x is $[0, 2^{20}]$?
3. How to prove the induction formula of $f_k(x)$

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: It would probably be better if you included the question instead of a link in the body of your question.

Comment: Oh, thank you for that